# Stop WordPress from hi-jacking CodeIgniter URLs using .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, wordpress, codeigniter

WordPress is installed in the root web directory:

```
/var/www/html/
```

CodeIgniter is installed in a sub-directory:

```
/var/www/html/ciapp/
```

When I access `http://www.example.com/ciapp/` the main CI controller is accessed and executed correctly.

However, if I try to access my main CI controller directly like so:

```
http://www.example.com/ciapp/main/
```

I get WordPress's 404 page. Also, if I attempt to access a function of my main controller like this:

```
http://www.example.com/ciapp/main/myfunction/
```

I also get the same 404 page.

So, basically, WordPress is ignoring the `/ciapp/` directory by default, but it's not ignoring any URL requests that are added to it. Here is my WordPress .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

So what kind of RewriteCond do I need to add to the WordPress .htaccess for it to ignore the /ciapp/ directory and any URI request that uses that directory as well?

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?ciapp
```

But it didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

if url == any of these, do NOT use index.php to serve them.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|img|forums|ciapp|robots\.txt)
```

else, use index.php

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

if url == ciapp/* , use ciapp/index.php to server them.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?ciapp/(.*) /ciapp/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you clarify where in my .htaccess to put these?

Comment: Also that first condition you have there, you say the url has to == the things listed. So do I have to add every possible url for my CI app into that condition? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error on all pages when I add that last line in. Can you clarify where to put the code in the .htaccess?